# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. Why am i getting this error? please help

Tags: python

```
def get_top_k(frequency, k):
    temp = frequency
    key = ""
    tvalues = []
    values = []
    kk = int(k)
    i = 0
    for i in temp.keys():
        key = i
        num = [int(frequency[key])]
        tvalues += num
    tvalues = bubble_sort(tvalues)
    i = 0
    for i in kk:
        num = [int(tvalues[i])]
        values += num
    print(values)
    i = 0
    result = {}
    for i in kk:
        result += {(str(temp[values[i]])):(int(values[i]))}
    return result
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you meant

```
for i in range(kk):
```

Comment: Explained further: If you do need to iterate over a sequence of numbers, the built-in function range() comes in handy. It generates lists containing arithmetic progressions, e.g.:
    `>>> range(10)`
    `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
(source: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html)  Here's the link for "range" for 3.3 - http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range

Answer (score 3):

a bit off topic, but:

```
for i in temp.keys():
    key = i
    num = [int(frequency[key])]
    tvalues += num

should just be:

tvalues = temp.values()
```

example:

```
>>> D = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
>>> D.keys()
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
>>> D.values()
[1, 3, 2, 4]
>>> D.items()
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('d', 4)]
>>>
```

and it looks like your code could be changed to this:

```
>>> D = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
>>> def get_top_k(D, k):
...     return sorted(D.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])[:k]
... 
>>> get_top_k(D, 2)
[('d', 4), ('c', 3)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `for i in kk` and `kk` is just an integer.  You can't iterate over an integer, you can only iterate over a sequence/iterable.

You probably want `for i in range(kk)` if you want to iterate from 0 to `(kk-1)`.

Comment: `xrange` wouldn't hurt either. ;)

Comment: @Aviral if it's not Python 3.x :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `kk = int(k)`

`kk` is only one single number, not an array of numbers

What are you trying to do, for us to help you fixing it?